# Repeat process with different sorting and stopping condition

Tags: scala

My data has two lists of the same class (let's say `suppliers` and `consumers`). Several class properties could be used for sorting (see `group` and `subGroup` below). I need to find `supplier` - `consumer` pairs with best scores. The structures are prohibitively big to evaluate each `supplier` against each `consumer`. I need to apply following logic:

1. Select the most detailed sorting attribute
2. Sort both sets by selected attribute
3. Calculate candidate scores for pairs
4. Process members with best scores and eliminated them from the original sets
5. Choose next less detailed attribute
6. Continue with next iteration from step #2 until either all `suppliers` or all `customers` are assigned

How could I code this process w/o coding each iteration explicitly? The only think different for each iteration is sort attribute and stopping attribute. Does Scala has any support changing these parameters dynamically?

Very simplified code showing "score processing" by `subGroup`:

```
case class c (
             group : String,
             subGroup : String,
             someValues : Double
             )

case class option (
                    supplier : c,
                    consumer : c,
                    score : Double
                  )


val supplier = List(
  c("a", "aa", 1),
  c("a", "aa", 2),
  c("a", "ab", 1),
  c("b", "ba", 1),
  c("b", "bb", 1),
  c("b", "bb", 4)
)


val consumer = List(
  c("a", "aa", 4),
  c("a", "aa", 2),
  c("a", "ab", 3),
  c("b", "ba", 3),
  c("b", "bb", 3),
  c("b", "bb", 3)
)

// finding different score options
val supplierSorted = supplier.sortBy(x => x.subGroup) //how to write the sort dynamically?
val consumerSorted = consumer.sortBy(x => x.subGroup) //how to write the sort dynamically?
val options = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[option]()

var sIndex: Int = 0
var cIndex: Int = 0

while(sIndex < supplierSorted.length){
  val s = supplierSorted(sIndex)
  var cIncrease = 0
  var c = consumerSorted(cIndex)
  while (s.subGroup == c.subGroup && cIndex + cIncrease < supplierSorted.length){ //how to write the first condition dynamically?
    options += option(s, c, math.abs(s.someValues - c.someValues))
    cIncrease += 1
    if(cIndex + cIncrease < supplierSorted.length) c = supplierSorted(sIndex + cIncrease)
  }
  sIndex += 1
  if(sIndex < supplierSorted.length && supplierSorted(sIndex).subGroup != s.subGroup) { //how to write the condition dynamically?
    cIndex = math.min(consumerSorted.length, cIndex + cIncrease)
  }

}
```

Do you see a way how to apply same logic to the `group` w/o rewriting the second section again?

I was considering creating method that would return value based iteration name provided as parameter to this method. The validation would rely on the method value instead of actual property values. However, I'm concerned with the sort performance as well as real problem requires multiple parameters with different data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inject logic via function, simple:

```
def groupCalculations = calculations(_.group)
def subGroupCalculations = calculations(_.subGroup)

def calculations(f: c => String) = {
  // finding different score options
  val supplierSorted = supplier.sortBy(f) //how to write the sort dynamically?
  val consumerSorted = consumer.sortBy(f) //how to write the sort dynamically?
  val options = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[option]()

  while (sIndex < supplierSorted.length) {
    val s = supplierSorted(sIndex)
    var cIncrease = 0
    var c = consumerSorted(cIndex)
    //condition dynamic via function - f
    while (f(s) == f(c) && cIndex + cIncrease < supplierSorted.length) { 
      options += option(s, c, math.abs(s.someValues - c.someValues))
      cIncrease += 1
      if (cIndex + cIncrease < supplierSorted.length)
        c = supplierSorted(sIndex + cIncrease)
    }
    sIndex += 1
    //condition dynamic via function - f
    if (sIndex < supplierSorted.length && f(supplierSorted(sIndex)) != f(s.subGroup)) {
      cIndex = math.min(consumerSorted.length, cIndex + cIncrease)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: @[Ivan Kurchenko], thank you for suggestions. While `Option` feels promising, it requires type specification `Option[data type]` and I don't see how to work around changing it. Any suggestions? Also `def groupCalculation = calculations(_.group)` returns syntax error `Cannot resolve symbol group` (so does the 2nd declaration). Does your example compiles correctly on your side?

Comment: @Dan my bad - fixed it.

Comment: @[Ivan Kurchenko] I understand the logic now - it's pretty powerful, THANK YOU! Last follow-up question: is this technique name in Scala (i.e. declaring parameter as `f(f: c => String)`? (p.s. I'll accept the response and then will edit it so that fully functional code is available for other who ever need it).

Comment: @Dan nothing special there, you just extract part of not common logic to function - usually it's called higher order functions, but idea as you can see pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Adding complete code including minor syntax fixes based on @Ivan Kurcheno's answer (I was trying to edit Ivan's answer directly, but the edit was rejected).

This example is end to end solution to the original question:

```
case class c (
                   group : String,
                   subGroup : String,
                   someValues : Double
                 )

    case class option (
                        supplier : c,
                        consumer : c,
                        option : String,
                        score : Double
                      )


    def calculations(supplier : List[c], consumer : List[c], f: c => String) : List[option] = {
      // finding different score options
      val options = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[option]()
      val supplierSorted = supplier.sortBy(f) //sort changes based on parameter f (either subGroup or group)
      val consumerSorted = consumer.sortBy(f)
      var sIndex: Int = 0
      var cIndex: Int = 0

      while (sIndex < supplierSorted.length) {
        val s = supplierSorted(sIndex)
        var cIncrease = 0
        var c = consumerSorted(cIndex)
        //condition dynamic via function - f
        while (f(s) == f(c) && cIndex + cIncrease < supplierSorted.length) {
          options += option(s, c, f.toString(), math.abs(s.someValues - c.someValues))
          cIncrease += 1
          if (cIndex + cIncrease < supplierSorted.length)
            c = supplierSorted(cIndex + cIncrease)
        }
        sIndex += 1
        //condition dynamic via function - f
        if (sIndex < supplierSorted.length && f(supplierSorted(sIndex)) != f(s)) {
          cIndex = math.min(consumerSorted.length, cIndex + cIncrease)
        }

      }
      options.toList
    }

    val supplier = List(
      c("a", "aa", 1),
      c("a", "aa", 2),
      c("a", "ab", 1),
      c("b", "ba", 1),
      c("b", "bb", 1),
      c("b", "bb", 4)
    )
    val consumer = List(
      c("a", "aa", 4),
      c("a", "aa", 2),
      c("a", "ab", 3),
      c("b", "ba", 3),
      c("b", "bb", 3),
      c("b", "bb", 3)
    )
    def subGroupCalculations = {calculations(supplier, consumer, _.subGroup)}
    //logic selecting pairs with good enough score found in subgroup
    //and removing matched suppliers and customers would happen here
    // - just showing found pairs instead:
    println("Options found: " + subGroupCalculations.length)
    subGroupCalculations.foreach(o
    => println("[" + o.consumer.group + "," + o.consumer.subGroup + "] - [" + o.supplier.group + "," + o.supplier.subGroup
        + "] has score " + o.option, o.score)
    )

    def groupCalculations = {calculations(supplier, consumer, _.group)}
    //logic selecting pairs with good enough score found in group
    //and removing matched suppliers and customers would happen here
    // - just showing found pairs instead (notice, there are more combination due to using more generic attribute):
    println("Options found: " + groupCalculations.length)
    groupCalculations.foreach(o
    => println("[" + o.consumer.group + "," + o.consumer.subGroup + "] - [" + o.supplier.group + "," + o.supplier.subGroup
        + "] has score " + o.option, o.score)
    )
```